# Passing variable (from command line) into Class Constructor

Tags: c++, variables, constructor, parameter-passing

I'm having a problem passing a variable(array_size) I take from the user using command line. I need to pass this variable to HashMap constructor. In constructor if I change "array_size" to f.e 1000, it works , but i need it to be "variable" :)
This is my code, i would really appreciate any help.
Cheers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int counter = 1;

class HashEntry
{
    public:
        string key, value;
        HashEntry(string key, string value)
        {
            this->key = key;
            this->value = value;
        }
};

class HashMap
{
    private:
        HashEntry **table;

    public:
        HashMap()
        {
            table = new HashEntry*[array_size];
            for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
            table[i] = NULL;
        }

        void put(string key, string value, int option, int array_size)
        {
            int _key = atoi(key.c_str());
            int hash = _key;
            if(option == 1)
            {
                while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->key != key)
                {
                    counter++;
                    hash = (hash + 10);
                        }
                hash = hash  % array_size;
            }
            else if(option == 2)
            {
                while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->key != key)
                {
                    counter++;
                    hash = (hash + 10 + counter*counter) % array_size;
                        }
            }
            else if(option == 3)
            {
                while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->key != key)
                {
                    counter++;
                    hash = (hash + counter*(_key%(array_size-2)+1));
                    if(hash >= array_size)
                    {
                        hash = 0;
                    }
                }
                hash = hash % array_size;
            }

            if(table[hash] == NULL)
            {
                table[hash] = new HashEntry(key, value);

            }           
            else
                    {
                if (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->key == key)
                {
                    table[hash]->value;
                }               
                else
                {                       
                    table[hash] = new HashEntry(key, value);
                }
            }   
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HashMap map;
    string key, value;
    int array_size;

    array_size = atoi(argv[2]);
    int option = atoi(argv[1]);
    int records;
    cin>>records;

    for(int x = 0; x<records; x++)
    {
        cin >> key;
        cin >> value;
        map.put(key, value, option, array_size);
    }
    cout << counter << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To get an integer value from command line, accept it as string array item in `main()` or string in `WinMain()`, depending on your platform, convert `argv[1]` or another argument using `strtol()` or analog to an integer value, and then pass it to constructor. You should get exact details in your C textbook. All this has nothing common with constructing of an object, the latter is principally another topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array_size variable is in the scope of the `main` function. If you wanted this code to just work, you could make array_size have global scope by putting it outside the main function (i.e. at the top of the file). But what you really should do, is pass the array_size in the constructor of the HashMap class.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int counter = 1;

class HashEntry
{
    public:
        string key, value;
        HashEntry(string key, string value)
        {
            this->key = key;
            this->value = value;
        }
};

class HashMap
{
    private:
        HashEntry **table;
        int array_size;

    public:
        HashMap(int size) :
            array_size(size)
        {
            table = new HashEntry*[array_size];
            for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
            table[i] = NULL;
        }

        void put(string key, string value, int option, int array_size)
        {
            int _key = atoi(key.c_str());
            int hash = _key;
            if(option == 1)
            {
                while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->key != key)
                {
                    counter++;
                    hash = (hash + 10);
                        }
                hash = hash  % array_size;
            }
            else if(option == 2)
            {
                while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->key != key)
                {
                    counter++;
                    hash = (hash + 10 + counter*counter) % array_size;
                        }
            }
            else if(option == 3)
            {
                while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->key != key)
                {
                    counter++;
                    hash = (hash + counter*(_key%(array_size-2)+1));
                    if(hash >= array_size)
                    {
                        hash = 0;
                    }
                }
                hash = hash % array_size;
            }

            if(table[hash] == NULL)
            {
                table[hash] = new HashEntry(key, value);

            }           
            else
                    {
                if (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->key == key)
                {
                    table[hash]->value;
                }               
                else
                {                       
                    table[hash] = new HashEntry(key, value);
                }
            }   
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string key, value;
    int array_size;

    array_size = atoi(argv[2]);
    int option = atoi(argv[1]);
    int records;
    cin>>records;

    HashMap map(array_size);

    for(int x = 0; x<records; x++)
    {
        cin >> key;
        cin >> value;
        map.put(key, value, option, array_size);
    }
    cout << counter << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone ! All of your feedback has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh. Doesn't anyone learn about initialization any more? Don't create the `HashMap` object until you know how large it should be, and give `HashMap` a constructor that takes an argument that provides the desired size.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `array_size` parameter to your `HashMap` constructor, and instantiate the `map` object after you know the size of the array that's needed.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int counter = 1;

class HashEntry {
public:
    string key, value;
    HashEntry (string key, string value)
    {
        this->key = key;
        this->value = value;
    }
};

class HashMap {
private:
    HashEntry **table;

public:
    HashMap (int array_size)    // Add array_size parameter to constructor
    {
        table = new HashEntry*[array_size];
        for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
            table[i] = NULL;
    }

    void put (string key, string value, int option, int array_size)
    {
        int _key = atoi (key.c_str ());
        int hash = _key;
        if (option == 1) {
            while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->key != key) {
                counter++;
                hash = (hash + 10);
            }
            hash = hash  % array_size;
        }
        else if (option == 2) {
            while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->key != key) {
                counter++;
                hash = (hash + 10 + counter*counter) % array_size;
            }
        }
        else if (option == 3) {
            while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->key != key) {
                counter++;
                hash = (hash + counter*(_key % (array_size - 2) + 1));
                if (hash >= array_size) {
                    hash = 0;
                }
            }
            hash = hash % array_size;
        }

        if (table[hash] == NULL) {
            table[hash] = new HashEntry (key, value);

        }
        else {
            if (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->key == key) {
                table[hash]->value;
            }
            else {
                table[hash] = new HashEntry (key, value);
            }
        }
    }
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string key, value;
    int array_size;

    array_size = atoi (argv[2]);
    int option = atoi (argv[1]);
    int records;
    cin >> records;

    HashMap map (array_size);   // Declare map using new constructor

    for (int x = 0; x<records; x++) {
        cin >> key;
        cin >> value;
        map.put (key, value, option, array_size);
    }
    cout << counter << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A variable defined in a function, including `main` is only visible within that function.

You need to pass the size from `main` into the constructor

```
HashMap(int array_size)
{
    table = new HashEntry*[array_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    table[i] = NULL;
}
```

Then down in `main`

```
array_size = atoi(argv[2]);
HashMap map(array_size); // now create the hashmap
```

## but...

Never use user input without making dang sure it is good. What if the user provides "fubar" instead of a number? What if the user specifies -10? Or 14.998? `atoi` is bad at handing this. Instead use [`strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) or [`std::stoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul). Both only accept positive numbers and are easy to test for out of range values and invalid input characters.

Storing `array_size` inside `HashMap` as a member variable is also a good idea. A class should contain and protect all information on which it relies.

```
HashMap(unsigned int size): array_size(size)
{
    table = new HashEntry*[array_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    table[i] = NULL;
}
```

and one new private member variable

```
unsigned int array_size;
```

Note that it is `unsigned`. You can't have a negative-sized array, so why even allow the possibility? The compiler, with sufficient warnings enabled, will catch the mistake if a negative value is supplied.

And strongly consider replacing `HashEntry **` with a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). With the current pointer approach you pick up a lot of memory management that you are not currently performing. Your program leaks memory like a sieve. The vector also would save you from violating [the Rule of Three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).